# How can automate my current C script to automatically extract the correct device name out of the three device names?

Tags: c, linux

I see that there are many ways to find the MAC address of all the devices, especially for Ubuntu. But, I want to automatically know the name of only the MAC address of my laptop and not wired connections, type-C sockets, etc.

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: wlp59s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 9c:b6:d0:b8:6d:db brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
9: enx00e04c680999: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e0:4c:68:09:99 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

I get this output on using `ip -a link` and I somehow figured that wlp59s0 is the name of my laptop device for MAC purposes.

I have a C code that requests the name of the device, how can automate my current C script to automatically extract the wlp59s0 name out of the three device names?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show your C code, its actual output and the expected output.

Comment: BTW: there are no C scripts.

Comment: |If you want to script use |Python. What did you try so far. No effort usually means question closed

Answer (score 1):

First, you can have a better command: instead of `ip -a link`, you can refine with

```
ip -a link | grep -v "lo:" | grep "state UP" | sed 's/.*: \(.*\)*:.*/\1/'
```

Explanation:

- `ip -a link` display the available links
- `grep -v "lo:"` will filter out loopback interface
- `grep "state UP"` will filter only on interfaces (you could tune this one)
- `sed 's/.*: \(.*\)*:.*/\1/'` will only keep what's between colon (`:`)

Try this command, you should have the following result:

```
wlp59s0
```

Now, it will be easier to process in C, using `popen` to deals with process output like files.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char line[256];
    // escaped \ to \\
    // " replaced with ' to avoid escape them
    FILE * f = popen("ip -a link | grep -v 'lo:' | grep 'state UP' | sed 's/.*: \\(.*\\)*:.*/\\1/'", "r");
    
    printf("Found nics:\n");
    while (fgets( line, sizeof line, f)) {
        printf("%s\n", line);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works on native Ubuntu but still need to figure out for Windows WSL systems. Is there possibly a command that can be used across operating systems such as Windows, Ubuntu, Ubuntu on Windows, etc?